# Почему не срабатывает анимация у DataGridRow?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm, wpf-datagrid

Пытаюсь сделать анимацию `DataGriwRow` для состояния `EsEnabled = "False"` некоторых строк при определённых условиях. Определил отдельную булевую переменную для этого дела, если в `XAML` указываю `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWinnerAccess}" Value="false">`, то мигают все строки, если `true`, то ни одна не мигает. О_О При этом стиль второй анимации работает исправно.
`XAML`:

```
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsAccess}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWinnerAccess}" Value="false">
              <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                    RepeatBehavior="0:0:5.5"
                                    FillBehavior="Stop"
                                    To="LightCoral"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                  </Storyboard>
                 </BeginStoryboard>
               </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
              </DataTrigger>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWinner}" Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:1"
                                          To="3 From="3" To="0" BeginTime="0:0:5.5"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"/>
                      <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1"
                                          To="Red"
                                          AutoReverse="True"
                                          RepeatBehavior="0:0:5.5"
                                          FillBehavior="Stop"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                      <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:1"
                                          From="3" To="0"
                                          BeginTime="0:0:5.5"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"/>
                                          </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Свойства:

```
    private bool isWinnerAcces;
    public bool IsWinnerAccess
    {
        get => isWinnerAcces;
        set
        {
            if (isWinnerAcces == value) return;
            isWinnerAcces = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

        private bool isWinner;
        public bool IsWinner
        {
            get => isWinner;
            set
            {
                if (isWinner == value) return;
                isWinner = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool isAccess;
        public bool IsAccess
        {
            get => isAccess;
            set
            {
                if (isAccess == value) return;
                isAccess = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Comment: А вызов INPC где?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ есть оно) с ним такая же ситуация сохраняется...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось нужно было определить состояние триггера, когда он не срабатывает при помощи `<DataTrigger.ExitActions>` и убрать лишнюю переменную.

`XAML`:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsAccess}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAccess}" Value="false">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                        RepeatBehavior="0:0:2"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:5.5"
                                                        To="LightCoral"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation From="Transparent"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWinner}" Value="true">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:1"
                                                            To="3"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1"
                                                        To="Red"
                                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                                        RepeatBehavior="0:0:5.5"
                                                        FillBehavior="Stop"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                                        <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:1"
                                                            From="3" To="0"
                                                            BeginTime="0:0:5.5"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

`Код позади`:

```
private bool isWinner;
        public bool IsWinner
        {
            get => isWinner;
            set
            {
                if (isWinner == value) return;
                isWinner = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool isAccess = true;
        public bool IsAccess
        {
            get => isAccess;
            set
            {
                if (isAccess == value) return;
                isAccess = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```